# What to do when a answer should actually be an edit to an existing answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

To keep the discussion about how to deal with specific question/answer/comment issues that arise, here is one I noticed:

In this question [How, if at all, are you compressing your recordings?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/344/how-if-at-all-are-you-compressing-your-recordings/409#409) there is a nice answer by @Jamie describing X3 compression. Down a bit is another answer that provides the references for that compression by @Aarhus, but it's a separate answer and it doesn't have any votes so they don't appear together.

To me, it would make the most sense to have that paper citation within @Jamie's answer. Interestingly the link provided to X3 on GitHub has a readme file, and that readme links to the Johnson et al 2013 paper, but those links are broken. Obviously I could search for the paper by the citation info listed there, but since @Aarhus already shared it in the same question/answer thread, to me it seems very streamlined to have them together.

What do other people think? Is it too late to add that citation and link in as an EDIT to @Jamie's answer? Is that too much meddling? Curious to hear everyone's thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

My preference is to encourage community members (in this example, @Aarhus) to embrace moderator type roles as a first line of action.

In this case, I might comment on @Aarhus to encourage them to (1) comment on the original post, asking them to add the reference, or (2) edit the post themselves to include the link (reminding them that this is a community run platform).

Ultimately, it would be nice to ‘Tidy’ up any given Q&A, but hopefully if we can encourage users to take a more pro-active role in this, we won’t need as much house-cleaning.

Comment: I like that approach. Will give that a go on this specific scenario and see how it goes :)